# Point2D data type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

Learning Haskell....

Stuck with this message when I write the following code. Looks like there is some problem with the type declaration/ constructor.

**Error message : Not in scope: type constructor or class `Point2D'**

ps: I am facing a similar problem with Marklist which I thought was an alias for (String, Int). Do suggest. Are there newer names for these type declarations ?

```
distance :: Point2D -> Point2D -> Int
distance (x1, y1) (x2, y2) = 
sqrt(sqr (x1-x2) + sqr (y1-y2))
where
    sqr :: Float -> Float
    sqr x = x * x
```

Comment: Because you did not **define** Point2D, and it is not a type that come with Prelude. Judging from the function, are you missing `type Point2D = (Int, Int)`?

Comment: Also, there are other type issues.

Comment: Thanks @MMZK1526, got it. I was watching some lecturers and assumed this type statement was part of Prelude. Also, it should be Point2D -> Point2D -> Float.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That's why you also need to convert int (namely x1 - x2) to float. `fromIntegral`.